# How to display fragments with Ajax using Thymeleaf?

Tags: ajax, spring, thymeleaf

I have a problem where I need to save the state of my sorting columns and expanded tabs on a grid result when user goes to different screens and go back. Those different screen are basically fragments that we display to the user like adding a new item is a fragment to shows up in the top of the grid, but for that we're doing an entire refresh on the screen and then we lose our expanded items on the search grid and the user don't want that.
To avoid it we're starting to move to Ajax.
So once the user clicks on the Add button instead of refreshing the whole screen we'll just display the add fragment.

I found some links on how to do that, but so far none of them worked for me. I'm getting some erros so I'd like to know if you have any template that would help me out creating just a small sample of it.

I tried this approach:
http://www.marcelustrojahn.com/2016/08/spring-boot-thymeleaf-fragments-via-ajax/

But it didn't work because I'm using a different version so instead of GetMapping I used RequestMapping(value='/frag1', method=RequestMethod.GET)

Once I click on the button this on the console:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There was a problem retrieving the current GrailsWebRequest. This usually indicates a filter ordering issue (the 'springSecurityFilterChain' filter-mapping element must be positioned after the 'grailsWebRequest' element when using @Secured annotations).
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.determineUrl(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:90) ~[spring-security-core-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.getAttributes(AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:72) ~[spring-security-core-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:196) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53) ~[spring-security-core-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62) ~[spring-security-core-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58) ~[spring-security-core-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:305) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:182) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```